# Jquery based Arabic Keyboard

Tags: php, keyboard, virtual, arabic

Came across a requirement where I need to use virtual arabic keyboard so that people can type in directly in the text fields (e.g of arabic keyboard https://www.branah.com/arabic) .

I googled and came across some paid snippets. Do we have any opensource/free jquery based arabic keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: http://www.arabic-keyboard.org/keyboard/

[image]

Here is the snippet to add:

```
<input type="text" id="YourId" value=""  dir="rtl" class="keyboardInput"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.arabic-keyboard.org/keyboard/keyboard.css"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.arabic-keyboard.org/keyboard/keyboard.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

You can download `keyboard.js`, `keyboard.css` and `keyboard.png`, and upload them to your server to be independent.